# linux - output changes on terminal when file changes

Tags: linux, cat, tee, redirectstandardoutput

In a open terminal how could I see all the new content added to a file whenever a process writes data into it?

I've tried combinations with `cat` and `tee` but no success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use tail with -f

```
tail -f filename
```

Taken from the man pages for tail:

```
   -f, --follow[={name|descriptor}]
          output appended data as the file grows;

          an absent option argument means 'descriptor'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not do it with *cat*, you should use `tail -f <filename>` or `less <filename>` and push F in order to wait data.

```
$ man less
   ...
   F      Scroll  forward, and keep trying to read when the end of file is reached.  Normally this
          command would be used when already at the end of the file.  It is a way to  monitor  the
          tail  of  a file which is growing while it is being viewed.  (The behavior is similar to
          the "tail -f" command.)
   ...
```